# Can i test the entity framework down() migration as part of my build and deploy process?

Tags: entity-framework, build-process, build-automation, entity-framework-migrations

i use entity framework code based migrations. A simplified version of my workflow is...

Work against a local db, make changes to the model, test the up and the down migrations locally, commit code to the repo. My build server then pulls from the repo, builds, tests and deploys etc and i autorun any new migrations against a quality db. This works great, however i would like to also have my build server test my down migration.

I would like to achieve something where perhaps after deploying a new binary and running the up migration i run my integration tests to ensure they pass, then run the down migration and deploy my last known good binary and run my integration tests again.

If that deployment passes I then know my down migration works and perhaps more importantly i can create a single click script to downgrade my application to a previous version.  In theory then i could back out the deployments all the way back to the first deployment.

So does anyone know how i can instruct my binary to run the down() migrations for any up migrations it ran on deployment?